# What are the possible ways to store this data?

Tags: java

Well, I need this data to be used in at least two classes:

```
   String navHome = "home";
    String navAbout = "about";
    String navUpload = "upload";
    String navUploadProc = "uploadProc";
    String navStartUpload = "startUpload";
    String navContact = "contact";
    String navSearch = "search";
    String navManual = "manual";
    String navBackToGmis = "backToGmis";
```

I was thinking of just pasting that into other classes, but then it violates the principles of programming, since it's repeating the same thing. Text and XML files are not comfortable to store data, inheritance isn't an option, since Java doesn't support multiple inheritance... Any ideas?

Yeah, I know it will sound retarded to most of you, but I need tipps on this.

Comment: Put it as constants (public static final) in a class or interface.

Comment: An Arraylist?  What does "best" mean?

Comment: is this constant data or can this be updated programatically?

Comment: Use an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) if the values are constant.

Comment: @KennethGarza this is constant data, well most likely, though I might decide to change or add something later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are constants, then you can declare them in one class (or interface) and use them in another:

**A.java**:

```
public class A {
    public static final String navHome = "home";
    public static final String navAbout = "about";
    public static final String navUpload = "upload";
    public static final String navUploadProc = "uploadProc";
    public static final String navStartUpload = "startUpload";
    public static final String navContact = "contact";
    public static final String navSearch = "search";
    public static final String navManual = "manual";
    public static final String navBackToGmis = "backToGmis";

    . . .
}
```

**B.java**:

```
import static A.*; // or list each String in a separate import

public class B {
    . . . // code can use nav* as if they were declared in class B
}
```